# MongoDB and $geoWithin based on field value

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I'm looking to store documents that *each* has an array of: geopoint + max-distance field, for example:

```
{
    "title": "foo",
    "locations": [
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [1, 2],
        "max_distance": 10
      },
      {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [3, 4],
        "max_distance": 20
      }
    ]
}
```

I am wondering about the most efficient way to query all documents that are `$geoWithin` `max_distance` from an arbitrary geopoint. The problem I'm facing is that `max_distance` is kept in the db thus cannot be included in the query.